# How do I setup a rails project to use an edge source tree (not an installed gem) version of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like the rails 3.0 source tree in my project so I can use patches, etc. I don' want to freeze rails. I would like to be able to pull updates from the main repo too. How do I accomplish this?

In particular the [getting started guide](http://guides.rails.info/getting_started.html), has me confused with

```
As the root user:
# gem install bundler
# bundle install
```

If I install the bundled gems to my system then I'm not really running with the vendor/rails source tree. Do rails developers really edit-test-edit-test and then install gems to their system before trying out patches on an actual app?

--- Update ---

```
$ cd ~myapp/vendor/rails
$ bundler install
```

There are a bunch of gems in vendor/rails/vendor/cache. When I

```
$ cd ~/myapp
$ bundler install

... Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.0.0.beta1, runtime)' in any of the sources. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

How do I tell my app to get its gems with the bundled rails gems in vendor/rails/vendor/cache?

Answer (score 1):

```
gem "rails", :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git"
```

as per [ASCIIcasts Episode 201](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/201-bundler).

Answer (score 0):

After much screwing around, this is how to setup edge rails 3.0 beta.

```
mkdir -p myapp/vendor
cd myapp
git init
git submodule add git://github.com/rails/rails.git vendor/rails
git commit -m "Frozen Rails Edge as submodule"
ruby -r'rubygems' vendor/rails/railties/bin/rails .
```

Then edit myapp/Gemfile and change

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0.beta1'
```

to this

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0.beta1', :path => 'vendor/rails'
```

Finally, in myapp/

```
bundle check
bundle install
```

I found that any changes made to the rails source in vendor/rails will appear next time they load. There is no need to 'bundle install' after applying a patch.

References:
[1](http://ariejan.net/2009/01/04/how-to-start-a-rails-edge-app-the-easy-way/)
[2](http://blog.boffbowsh.co.uk/post/399252983/rails-3-thor-group)
[3](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/03/using-the-new-gem-bundler-today/)
[4](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/201-bundler)